# Table size is not changed after new column is added

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, alter-table, size

I am trying to check how the table size is going to be increased after adding new column with default values.

I use the following default values: `NULL`, `''`(empty string) and `some text`(some random text)` but it seems the table size is not changed.

I am using the following statements:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused '[Table_A]';

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A]
ADD [Loops] NVARCHAR(900)
CONSTRAINT [DF_Loops] DEFAULT('XXX') WITH VALUES;

EXEC sp_spaceused '[Table_A]';

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A]
DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Loops]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_A]
DROP COLUMN [Loops];
```

but the `sp_spaceused` always returns:

```
name                                               rows                 reserved           data               index_size         unused
------------------------------------------------- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
Table_A                                            73540994             8701688 KB         6658544 KB         2042976 KB         168 KB
```

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've added a new column, but (the Enterprise Edition of) SQL Server - if the default value is a runtime constant - will not update the existing pages that hold the table's data, it will be only a metadata change and that's the reason you see no increase in the space used.

For all intents and purposes (as Aaron mentioned in a comment), the values are there - and a `SELECT` will reveal them.

Think of it as SQL-Server black magic. It manages to store information in 0 bytes. Remus Rusanu has a nice blog post about this optimization and more details about what (magic) happens in the background and when you subsequently update the column:
**[Online non-NULL with values column add in SQL Server 2012](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/)**

The basic info about it, in MSDN docs, **[`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)**:

> Adding `NOT NULL` Columns as an Online Operation
>
> Starting with SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, adding a `NOT NULL` column with a default value is an online operation **when the default value is a runtime constant**. This means that the operation is completed almost instantaneously regardless of the number of rows in the table. **This is because the existing rows in the table are not updated during the operation**; instead, **the default value is stored only in the metadata of the table** and  **the value is looked up as needed in queries that access these rows**. This behavior is automatic; no additional syntax is required to implement the online operation beyond the `ADD` column syntax. A runtime constant is an expression that produces the same value at runtime for each row in the table regardless of its determinism. For example, the constant expression `'My temporary data'`, or the system function `GETUTCDATETIME()` are runtime constants. In contrast, the functions `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` are not runtime constants because a unique value is produced for each row in the table.